# Is there a way to clear the local SharePoint cache?

Tags: sharepoint

This isn't a coding question -- but we're looking for some SharePoint help.

Here's what we're seeing.

- Three of us are opening an Excel file in Teams (which is storing
  the document in SharePoint) and seeing different values.
- When I open it, I get a prompt that there are updates on the local version
  and do I want to merge them with the server version. (But doesn't
  matter if I saw Yes or No, I get the same prompt the next time I open
  this file.)
- Another user opens the file and sees different numbers
  than what we see. She makes changes and tries to save them but runs
  into a dialog box that says "Excel is updating your most recent
  changes" and it never ends. She eventually cancels.

What I suspect is that when the update is canceled, the local version is saved and it's not in sync with the server version. I think we're all looking at a version that failed when we used it earlier and tried to save changes. And now when we try to open the SharePoint version, it opens the version that's been saved locally.

The only way I got us to be able to finally see the same file values was to rename the SharePoint file. But this is going to break my code that consolidates files because the filename for this one file doesn't match the pattern of the rest of the files in the directory.

It seems that there used to be a way to purge all of the leftover, locally cached files -- I thought I had a way to do it it back in 2018. But when I've searched for help online, the only lead I've found is the **Office Upload Center**. None of us have that on our machine.

We're using Windows 10 Enterprise
Office 365 Desktop (version 2312)

Answer (score 0):

In the Options menu, if you scroll to the bottom of the Save panel, there's a button to clear the local cache.